# How can I use a Lambda function in creating a Wordle-esque game with Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda

So, I'm a Uni student, and for one of my modules we've been tasked with creating an interactive game or quiz or similar with Python. I thought I'd go with something that's essentially Wordle. My issue is that I can enter an 'A' into the game, but no other letters. If I try repeating the same code albeit with different labels, it just overwrites the functioning 'A' code.

I've been reading and it looks like I'll be able to use a 'lambda' function to get around this problem, but I don't really know how. I'll post my code below, and hopefully one of you wizards can help me.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
GameWindow = Tk()
GameWindow.title ("WORD5 - The 5X5 Word Spelling Game!")
GameWindow.geometry('2850x1000')
GameWindow.configure(bg="plum")
TileFrame=Frame(GameWindow, bg="green")
TileFrame.grid(row=0)
TileLine1Row1 = Label (TileFrame, text="box1", font=("Helvetica", 10), width=10, height=5, borderwidth=1,     relief="solid", bg="plum")
TileLine1Row1.grid(column=1,row=1,padx=15,pady = 10)
#
TileLine1Row2 = Label (TileFrame, text="box2", font=("Helvetica", 10), width=10, height=5,borderwidth=1,     relief="solid", bg="plum")
TileLine1Row2.grid(column=2,row=1,padx=15,pady = 10)
#T
TileLine1Row3 = Label (TileFrame, text="box3", font=("Helvetica", 10), width=10, height=5, borderwidth=1,     relief="solid", bg="plum")
TileLine1Row3.grid(column=3,row=1,padx=15,pady = 10)
#
```

TileLine1Row4 = Label (TileFrame, text="box4", font=("Helvetica", 10), width=10, height=5, borderwidth=1, relief="solid", bg="plum")
TileLine1Row4.grid(column=4,row=1,padx=15,pady = 10)

TileLine1Row5 = Label (TileFrame, text="box5", font=("Helvetica", 10), width=10, height=5, borderwidth=1, relief="solid", bg="plum")

#Now for the second row of tiles on the game

TileLine2Row1 = Label (TileFrame, text="box6", font=("Helvetica", 10), width=10, height=5, borderwidth=1, relief="solid", bg="plum")
TileLine2Row1.grid(column=1,row=2,padx=15,pady = 10)

TileLine2Row2 = Label (TileFrame, text="box7", font=("Helvetica", 10), width=10, height=5, borderwidth=1, relief="solid", bg="plum")
TileLine2Row2.grid(column=2,row=2,padx=15,pady = 10)

TileLine2Row3 = Label (TileFrame, text="box8", font=("Helvetica", 10), width=10, height=5, borderwidth=1, relief="solid", bg="plum")
TileLine2Row3.grid(column=3,row=2,padx=15,pady = 10)

TileLine2Row4 = Label (TileFrame, text="box9", font=("Helvetica", 10), width=10, height=5, borderwidth=1, relief="solid", bg="plum")
TileLine2Row4.grid(column=4,row=2,padx=15,pady = 10)

TileLine2Row5 = Label (TileFrame, text="box10", font=("Helvetica", 10), width=10, height=5, borderwidth=1, relief="solid", bg="plum")
TileLine2Row5.grid(column=5,row=2,padx=15,pady = 10)

```
#Rows and Columns defined numbers/ rows and columns placings
Trow = 1
Tcolumn = 1
#Defining where the letters go if a letter is pressed on the keyboard
def WhereLettersAreGoing ():
    global Trow
    global Tcolumn
    if Trow == 1:
        if Tcolumn == 1:
            #Add 1 to column count section
            WhereLettersGo = TileLine1Row1
        elif Tcolumn == 2:
            WhereLettersGo = TileLine1Row2
        elif Tcolumn == 3:
            WhereLettersGo = TileLine1Row3
        elif Tcolumn == 4:
            WhereLettersGo = TileLine1Row4
        elif Tcolumn == 5:
            WhereLettersGo = TileLine1Row5
        PutLetterIn (WhereLettersGo)
        Tcolumn = Tcolumn +1
def PutLetterIn (WhereLettersGo):
    WhereLettersGo.configure(text `your text`= "A")
# Define function to get the information about the Button
#Add in a check button?
#Button frame to section it up
ButtonsFrame=Frame(GameWindow, bg="blue")
ButtonsFrame.grid(row=1)

#Now, the buttons are below which represents the letters of the alphabet
#The buttons with letters A B C D E F G & H are on the top row of the letter button rows
#LetterAButton
LetterAButton = Button(ButtonsFrame, text="A", width=7, height=2, borderwidth=5, relief="raised", command = WhereLettersAreGoing)
LetterAButton.grid(column=1, row=4,padx=2,pady = 2)
#LetterBButton
LetterBButton = Button(ButtonsFrame, text="B", width=7, height=2, borderwidth=5, relief="raised")
LetterBButton.grid(column=2, row=4,padx=2,pady = 2)
#LetterCButton
LetterCButton = Button(ButtonsFrame, text="C", width=7, height=2, borderwidth=5, relief="raised")
LetterCButton.grid(column=3, row=4,padx=2,pady = 2)
#LetterDButton
LetterDButton = Button(ButtonsFrame, text="D", width=7, height=2, borderwidth=5, relief="raised")
LetterDButton.grid(column=4, row=4,padx=2,pady = 2)
#LetterEButton
LetterEButton = Button(ButtonsFrame, text="E", width=7, height=2, borderwidth=5, relief="raised")
LetterEButton.grid(column=5, row=4,padx=2,pady = 2)
#LetterFButton
LetterFButton = Button(ButtonsFrame, text="F", width=7, height=2, borderwidth=5, relief="raised")
LetterFButton.grid(column=6, row=4,padx=2,pady = 2)
#LetterGButton
LetterGButton = Button(ButtonsFrame, text="G", width=7, height=2, borderwidth=5, relief="raised")
LetterGButton.grid(column=7, row=4,padx=2,pady = 2)
#LetterHButton
LetterHButton = Button(ButtonsFrame, text="H", width=7, height=2, borderwidth=5, relief="raised")
LetterHButton.grid(column=8, row=4,padx=2,pady = 2)
#The buttons with letters I J K L M N O & P are on the second row of the button rows
#LetterIButton
LetterIButton = Button(ButtonsFrame, text="I", width=7, height=2, borderwidth=5, relief="raised")
LetterIButton.grid(column=1, row=5,padx=2,pady = 2)
#LetterJButton
LetterJButton = Button(ButtonsFrame, text="J", width=7, height=2, borderwidth=5, relief="raised")
LetterJButton.grid(column=2, row=5,padx=2,pady = 2)
#LetterKButton
LetterKButton = Button(ButtonsFrame, text="K", width=7, height=2, borderwidth=5, relief="raised")
LetterKButton.grid(column=3, row=5,padx=2,pady = 2)
#LetterLButton
LetterLButton = Button(ButtonsFrame, text="L", width=7, height=2, borderwidth=5, relief="raised")
LetterLButton.grid(column=4, row=5,padx=2,pady = 2)
#LetterMButton
LetterMButton = Button(ButtonsFrame, text="M", width=7, height=2, borderwidth=5, relief="raised")
LetterMButton.grid(column=5, row=5,padx=2,pady = 2)
#LetterNButton
LetterNButton = Button(ButtonsFrame, text="N", width=7, height=2, borderwidth=5, relief="raised")
LetterNButton.grid(column=6, row=5,padx=2,pady = 2)
#LetterOButton
LetterOButton = Button(ButtonsFrame, text="O", width=7, height=2, borderwidth=5, relief="raised")
LetterOButton.grid(column=7, row=5,padx=2,pady = 2)
#LetterPButton
LetterPButton = Button(ButtonsFrame, text="P", width=7, height=2, borderwidth=5, relief="raised")
LetterPButton.grid(column=8, row=5,padx=2,pady = 2)


#LetterQButton
LetterQButton = Button(ButtonsFrame, text="Q", width=7, height=2, borderwidth=5, relief="raised")
LetterQButton.grid(column=2, row=6,padx=2,pady = 2)
#LetterRButton
LetterRButton = Button(ButtonsFrame, text="R", width=7, height=2, borderwidth=5, relief="raised")
LetterRButton.grid(column=3, row=6,padx=2,pady = 2)
#LetterSButton
LetterSButton = Button(ButtonsFrame, text="S", width=7, height=2, borderwidth=5, relief="raised")
LetterSButton.grid(column=4, row=6,padx=2,pady = 2)
#LetterTButton
LetterTButton = Button(ButtonsFrame, text="T", width=7, height=2, borderwidth=5, relief="raised")
LetterTButton.grid(column=5, row=6,padx=2,pady = 2)
#LetterUButton
LetterUButton = Button(ButtonsFrame, text="U", width=7, height=2, borderwidth=5, relief="raised")
LetterUButton.grid(column=6, row=6,padx=2,pady = 2)
#LetterVButton
LetterVButton = Button(ButtonsFrame, text="V", width=7, height=2, borderwidth=5, relief="raised")
LetterVButton.grid(column=7, row=6,padx=2,pady = 2)

#LetterWButton
LetterWButton = Button(ButtonsFrame, text="W", width=7, height=2, borderwidth=5, relief="raised")
LetterWButton.grid(column=3, row=7,padx=2,pady = 2)
#LetterXButton
LetterXButton = Button(ButtonsFrame, text="X", width=7, height=2, borderwidth=5, relief="raised")
LetterXButton.grid(column=4, row=7,padx=2,pady = 2)
#LetterYButton
LetterYButton = Button(ButtonsFrame, text="Y", width=7, height=2, borderwidth=5, relief="raised")
LetterYButton.grid(column=5, row=7,padx=2,pady = 2)
#LetterZButton
LetterZButton = Button(ButtonsFrame, text="Z", width=7, height=2, borderwidth=5, relief="raised")
LetterZButton.grid(column=6, row=7,padx=2,pady = 2)

#Closing the game window loop
GameWindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: Unrelated to your issue of entering 'A', I'd recommend that you get comfortable with using lists and for loops to reduce all the repetitive code in your solution.

Comment: Fix the code formatting as it is hard to read.